# Jquery sparklines: Possible to have different tooltips?

Tags: sparklines

I'm using JQuery Sparklines (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline) to display a line graph where each tick in the graph corresponds to an hour interval of the current day. I've formatted the tooltip as such:

```
<span style=\"color: {{color}}\">&#9679;</span> {{offset:names}} - {{y}}{{suffix}}</span>
```

where `offset:names` corresponds to the hour of the day (0 = 00:00, 1 = 01:00) etc.

The graph updates with live data. The problem is that if a point is in the future, I don't want to display the {{y}} value in the tooltip - just the time of day. Is it possible to do this? If not is there another way to get the same effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! Using tooltipFormatter, I did something like this:

```
sparkOpts.CurrentTimeGroup = currentTimeGroup;
  sparkOpts.tooltipFormatter = function(sparklines, options, point)
  {
    if(point.x <= options.mergedOptions.CurrentTimeGroup)
      return "<div class=\"jqsfield\"><span style=\"color: " + point.color + "\">&#9679;</span>" + options.get("tooltipValueLookups").names[point.x] + " - " + point.y + options.get("tooltipSuffix") + "</div>";
    else
      return "<div class=\"jqsfield\"><span style=\"color: " + point.color + "\">&#9679;</span>" + options.get("tooltipValueLookups").names[point.x] + "</div>";
  };
```